# Parse.com Query gradually when sorted by location

Tags: android, parse-platform

I know how to query by distance, it works very well.

**The question is:**
How to get the first 10 closest item, then the 10 after that and so on ?

```java
ParseGeoPoint userLocation = (ParseGeoPoint) userObject.get("location");
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PlaceObject");
query.whereNear("location", userLocation);
query.setLimit(10);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() { ... });
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, suppose a user (with a fixed latitude and longitude coordinates) wants to find out all the other users around him. I want to be able to show him closest 10 users to his position on a RecyclerView for example, than if the user continues scrolling, the app will ask Parse.com for the next 10 closest users, then will update the recyclerview, than if the user scrolls again we load the next 10....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `setSkip()` method: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#setSkip(int)

You could maybe put the query in a method which you call everytime you want to get 10 more results and then increment the skip value by 10.

```
ParseGeoPoint userLocation = (ParseGeoPoint) userObject.get("location");
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PlaceObject");
query.whereNear("location", userLocation);
query.setLimit(10);
query.setSkip(skipNum); //0 the firstTime, 10 the 2nd, 20 the 3rd, etc
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() { ... });
```